# UnityVS cannot attach to Unity Editor - Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, unityvs

I have bought UnityVS and it was working well with VS2010. Later Microsoft aquiared their company and now UnityVS is a free plugin with one difference: it is much more unstable.

I had several issues with new updates and finally I decided the move to completely new version which is called "Visual Studio Tools for Unity" instead of UnityVS.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition 2013 Update 4 (which is actually a VS Professional). Everything looks good but it attached to the process because the plug icon on lower right corner tells me it is attached to Unity Editor (My version of Unity Editor is 4.5.5f1). However when I click on "Attach to unity" button it only compiles and then does nothing (it doesn't lock). As a result I am unable to debug because it doesn't hit any breakpoint.

Please somebody help me because even [their support page](http://unityvs.com/support/) doesn't show any useful link to talk with them (It is Microsoft anyways!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798816/visual-studio-debugger-not-attaching-to-unity/37826299#37826299

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours I found a solution! The only this I did was to double click on the plug icon in lower right corner of visual studio and clicked on the custom IP and then instead of 192.168.0.xxx (My IP) I entered 127.0.0.1 and for the port I used the port that is shown already for the unity instance. That's it. :)

Comment: Hi, Sebastien from VSTU team here. If you encounter any issue feel free to drop us a mail at vstusp [at] microsoft [dot] com. A good advice is to allow both Unity and Devenv processes in your firewall configuration. Using 127.0.0.1 allow you to use the loopback adapter and so to bypass firewall restrictions. Regards

Comment: As of 2018 this issue still sporadically exists, however it appears as though the custom IP option is no longer available, or at least it moved.