# Visual studio can't attach to Unity Editor after Xamarin install

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, mono, unity-game-engine

After I installed the Xamarin tools from this link: https://www.xamarin.com/vs-download?utm_source=visualstudio&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=download&utm_campaign=installer

My Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition is not attaching to My Unity Editor (x64, v5.3.5). It simply builds the project, which it's not supposed to do, Should be going through UnityEditor and attaching to it.

Visual Studio has no problems finding the Editor, as I can see the Unity instance from my "Attach to Unity" combobox.

I had no previous problems attaching my debugger before the Xamarin install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the only solution is to deinstall Xamarin.

I did file a bug to the Visual Studio and Xamarin team:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42023

Here's another question, covering the same topic.
[Visual Studio Debugger not attaching to Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798816/visual-studio-debugger-not-attaching-to-unity/37826299)

Comment: The issue has been solved and will be updated in the next release of VSTU which will come out shortly.